# Problems with android google maps api v2

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps

I'm gonna execute a simple map in eclipse, but I encounter force close error!
I didn't have problem with google api v1, but I couldn't run a project with google api v2!

Here is my logcat details:

```
 03-07 23:56:45.755: I/dalvikvm(331): Could not find method android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.<init>, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.a
03-07 23:56:45.755: W/dalvikvm(331): VFY: unable to resolve direct method 91: Landroid/app/AlertDialog$Builder;.<init> (Landroid/content/Context;I)V
03-07 23:56:45.764: D/dalvikvm(331): VFY: replacing opcode 0x70 at 0x0037
03-07 23:56:45.764: E/dalvikvm(331): Could not find class 'android.app.Notification$Builder', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.a
03-07 23:56:45.764: W/dalvikvm(331): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 40 (Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;) in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;
03-07 23:56:45.774: D/dalvikvm(331): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0029
03-07 23:56:45.774: D/dalvikvm(331): VFY: dead code 0x002b-0071 in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;.a (ILandroid/content/Context;)V
03-07 23:56:45.794: D/dalvikvm(331): DexOpt: couldn't find field Landroid/content/res/Configuration;.smallestScreenWidthDp
03-07 23:56:45.794: W/dalvikvm(331): VFY: unable to resolve instance field 65
03-07 23:56:45.794: D/dalvikvm(331): VFY: replacing opcode 0x52 at 0x0012
03-07 23:56:45.794: D/dalvikvm(331): VFY: dead code 0x0014-0018 in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;.b (Landroid/content/res/Resources;)Z
03-07 23:56:45.804: I/dalvikvm(331): Could not find method android.app.Activity.getFragmentManager, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.showErrorDialogFragment
03-07 23:56:45.804: W/dalvikvm(331): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 32: Landroid/app/Activity;.getFragmentManager ()Landroid/app/FragmentManager;
03-07 23:56:45.814: D/dalvikvm(331): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0023
03-07 23:56:45.814: D/dalvikvm(331): VFY: dead code 0x0026-0030 in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;.showErrorDialogFragment (ILandroid/app/Activity;Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;ILandroid/content/DialogInterface$OnCancelListener;)Z
03-07 23:56:45.824: D/AndroidRuntime(331): Shutting down VM
03-07 23:56:45.824: W/dalvikvm(331): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
03-07 23:56:45.854: E/AndroidRuntime(331): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-07 23:56:45.854: E/AndroidRuntime(331): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mymap/com.example.mymap.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class fragment
03-07 23:56:45.854: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
03-07 23:56:45.854: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
03-07 23:56:45.854: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-07 23:56:45.854: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
03-07 23:56:45.854: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-07 23:56:45.854: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-07 23:56:45.854: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-07 23:56:45.854: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-07 23:56:45.854: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-07 23:56:45.854: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-07 23:56:45.854: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-07 23:56:45.854: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-07 23:56:45.854: E/AndroidRuntime(331): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class fragment
03-07 23:56:45.854: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:587)
03-07 23:56:45.854: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:386)
03-07 23:56:45.854: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
03-07 23:56:45.854: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
03-07 23:56:45.854: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
03-07 23:56:45.854: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
03-07 23:56:45.854: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at com.example.mymap.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
03-07 23:56:45.854: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-07 23:56:45.854: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
03-07 23:56:45.854: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  ... 11 more
03-07 23:56:45.854: E/AndroidRuntime(331): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 6587000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
03-07 23:56:45.854: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.D(Unknown Source)
03-07 23:56:45.854: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
03-07 23:56:45.854: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.x.T(Unknown Source)
03-07 23:56:45.854: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.x.S(Unknown Source)
03-07 23:56:45.854: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
03-07 23:56:45.854: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.nO(Unknown Source)
03-07 23:56:45.854: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
03-07 23:56:45.854: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
03-07 23:56:45.854: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
03-07 23:56:45.854: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
03-07 23:56:45.854: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2158)
03-07 23:56:45.854: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:297)
03-07 23:56:45.854: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
03-07 23:56:45.854: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  ... 19 more
```

This is my main.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
     Copyright (C) 2012 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- This can go anywhere in your layout (see other demos for some examples). -->
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

My MainActivity.java file:

```
package com.example.mymap;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

And the Manifest.xml file of my project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mymap"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <!-- External storage for caching. -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <!-- My Location -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

  <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyC82ObRRCXZe_217Z-ovx1VVIpLs-5IvIA"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Please help me, I've been really crazy!

Comment: change setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); to setContentView(R.layout.main); your xml file is called main.xml correct

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the following from your xml file

```
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```